# jq - select all non-empty unique values of a key matching a regex

Tags: arrays, json, search, jq

Here is my `JSON` file

```
[
    {
        "Body": [
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "webApplicationId": "/solr",
                "webServerName": "localhost"
            },
           {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "contextRoot": "/backoffice",
                "webApplicationId": "backoffice",
                "webServerName": "Catalina/localhost"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "discoveredName": "ImpExImportJob",
                "displayName": "ImpExImportJob",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-D2B53C681D503292",
                "toRelationships": {
                    "calls": [
                        "SERVICE-A744C713BB5D832B"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "discoveredName": "CronJobs"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
                "contextRoot": "/",
                "discoveredName": "www.example.com:443",
                "displayName": "www.example.com:443",
                "serviceType": "WebRequest",
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
                "contextRoot": "/service",
                "discoveredName": "www.example.com:443",
                "displayName": "www.example.com:443",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-96405085FB29CC50",
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
                "contextRoot": "/nodes",
                "discoveredName": "www.exampleA.com:443",
                "displayName": "www.exampleA.com:443",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-15578BCF4A5FF4D5",
                "toRelationships": {},
                "webServerName": "www.exampleA.com:443"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
                "contextRoot": "/",
                "discoveredName": "www.example.com:80",
                "displayName": "www.example.com:80",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-F9193C47A131E506",
                "toRelationships": {},
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:80"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My task - to select all *unique, non-empty* values of the `"webServerName"` key which have the web URL form, ending at `:443` and display all these values without double quotes one on each line.

The result should look like the following:

```
www.example.com:443
www.exampleA.com:443
```

Please note that `"webServerName"` is not present in certain objects and might have duplicate values as well.

I came up with the following jq filter

```
jq -r '[.[] |.Body | .[]  | select((.webServerName !=null) and (.webServerName | test ("\\w[a-z0-9-.]+.[a-z]{2,3}:443$")) ) ] | [.[].webServerName] | unique | .[]' services.json
```

My question - is there a much more elegant, less complicated filter with `jq` accomplishing the same?

P.S. One additional requirement - exclude values that have certain patterns in the `url`.
So for example the `url` contains `server-internal` in the `url`, then `www.server-internal.example.com:443` or `server-internal.b.example.com:443` should be filtered out.
Is the above better to do with regex or there are better ways?

Comment: I can provide an update to my answer, but remember to post all your requirements to the question in one shot

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should be more elaborate on why I used regex.

Comment: Thanks again, very nice and elegant. And if I want, I can add more exclusion condition by using  the expression ``test (a|b) | not``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could very simply use the recursive descent on the `webServerName` field, ignore the empty ones and select ones ending with `:443` using the `endswith/1` function which is much straightforward than using a regex based approach.

On the obtained result use the `unique` function to remove the duplicated entries.

```
[ .. | .webServerName? | select(. != null and endswith(":443")) ] | unique[]
```

Use the `-r` flag in command line to emit the output in raw output mode to loose the quotes.

Another variant involving `map`, traversing from top down

```
map(.Body[].webServerName | select(. != null and endswith(":443") ) ) | unique[]
```

---

OP had a follow-up requirement to ignore URLs containing the part `"server-internal"` for which you could add another condition to the select

```
map( .Body[].webServerName | 
  select( ( . != null and endswith(":443") ) and 
    ( test("server-internal") | not ) ) ) | 
unique[]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. Only one related question - if I want to add an additional condition that not only the value ends with ``":443"``, but also does not contain a pattern like ``my-hosting`` so URL ``www.internal.my-hosting-a.example.com:443"`` is not included in the result -  would ``inside`` or ``contains`` work, or better to use regex?